# increment cells inside sum function excel

Tags: excel, variables, sum, increment

I would like to know how to specify a cell in a sum function based on a variable.

For instance,

startpoint: a1 = 5
length: a2 = 10

i have data in b1 - b100.

I want a sum function sum(b(a1):b(a1+a2))
which would yield:
sum(b5:b15)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the non volatile INDEX function:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B,A1):INDEX(B:B,A1+A2))
```

[image]